# A fixed size div with text that stays inside of it

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a little widget, but CSS really isn't my strength.

[Code Pen Example](http://codepen.io/flxhindemo/pen/xdVodd)

I want the text inside my div to make a line break if it reaches the width limit and end in a `text-overflow: ellipsis` if it goes beyond the height limit. But I can't for the life of me figure it out.

Am I missing something obvious here or am I approaching it the wrong way?

EDIT: Apparently `overflow: ellipsis` only works on single line text and there is no perfect cross-browser solution yet.

Comment: What do you want to implement? It seems that you don't want text of last  line to be clipped. So try height: 105px; in .widget {...}

Comment: @Nimish I need the .widget to be a fixed height and the text needs to be cut off with ellipsis "..." if it goes beyond the height of the widget. I'm going to get text from an API and it will change from time to time so I can't change the height to fit the size of one specific paragraph.

Comment: [This](https://codepen.io/martinwolf/pen/qlFdp) might help you

Comment: @Nimish looks like a good start, I'll see if I can make use of that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add the css property white-space: pre-wrap; to your text and then you can write the text in the code the way you want it to be displayed on the webpage. The whitespace property will prevent the text from going outside the div. Also you can increase the size of your divs to fit the text.

Comment: The white-space: pre-wrap; doesn't seem to do anything for me. What do you mean by "write the text in the code"?
I can't change the div's height since it needs to be fixed for it's purpose and since the text will be gathered from an API, the text needs to be cut off at the bottom of the div.

Comment: The white-space property should provide a line break to the text on reaching the width limit of the div. And I guess that @Nimish has already solved the ellipsis problem. I'm sorry that I could not be of much help. I wrote "write the text in the code" because I didn't know that the API would render the text.

Comment: Oh I see, I already had the width limit figured out so that's why it didn't seem to do anything. I got the ellipsis problem solved for webkit but not Firefox or Edge..

Comment: Oh well, I don't know much about Firefox or Edge. So I can't help any further. My apologies.

Comment: No worries, I appreciate all the help!